# Merchant tools are not allowed for this account

Tags: coinbase-api

Why Coinbase doesn't let me use their merchant tools. I love them they are so cool and simple things that can let you accept bitcoin on your website. There is not another alternative to those like iframe payment or payment buttons like that.

Why it says you are account is not allowed to use merchant tools. Contacted coinbase for this issue didn't got respond from them.

Comment: Not a *programming* question suited for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Update merchant profile first of your coinbase account https://www.coinbase.com/merchant_profiles